# Compute forest loss for polygons in Google Earth Engine

Tags: polygon, google-earth-engine

My query is in two parts:

Part 1:
I am trying to calculate forest loss per polygon. I uploaded coordinate points to GEE and then I drew a polygon around the points. I created a buffer of 250m to the polygons. After that I then computed forest loss per the buffer feature collection I created but when I run the code it just returns an overall figure rather than forest loss per polygon.

```
// Make a list of Features.
var features = [
  ee.Feature(Diamante),
  ee.Feature(Romero),
  ee.Feature(Shintuya),
  ee.Feature(MLC)
];

// Create a FeatureCollection from the list and print it.
var fromList = ee.FeatureCollection(features);
print(fromList);

// Create a geodesic polygon.
var polygon = fromList.geometry()

// Compute a buffer of the polygon.
var buffer = polygon.buffer(250);

// Compute the centroid of the polygon.
var centroid = polygon.centroid();
Map.addLayer(buffer, {}, 'buffer');
Map.addLayer(centroid, {}, 'centroid');

// Get the forest loss image.
var lossImage = gfc.select(['loss']);

// Sum the values of forest loss pixels in the Congo Republic.
var stats = lossImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: buffer,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
print('pixels representing loss: ', stats.get('loss'));

// Set the scale for our calculations to the scale of the Hansen dataset
// which is 30m
var scale = gfc.projection().nominalScale();

// Create a variable for the original tree cover in 2000
var treeCover = gfc.select(['treecover2000']);

// Convert the tree cover layer because the treeCover by default is in
// hundreds of hectares, but the loss and gain layers are just in hectares!
treeCover = treeCover.divide(100);

// Create a variable for forest loss
var loss = gfc.select(['loss']);

// Create a variable for forest gain
var gain = gfc.select(['gain']);

// The units of the variables are numbers of pixels
// Here we are converting the pixels into actual area
// Dividing by 1 000 000 so that the final result is in km2
var areaCover = treeCover.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
                .divide(1000000).select([0],["areacover"]);

var areaLoss = loss.gt(0).multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).multiply(treeCover)
              .divide(1000000).select([0],["arealoss"]);

var areaGain = gain.gt(0).multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).multiply(treeCover)
              .divide(1000000).select([0],["areagain"]);

// Sum the values of loss pixels.
var statsLoss = areaLoss.reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  collection: buffer,
  scale: scale
});
// Sum the values of gain pixels.
var statsGain = areaGain.reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  collection: buffer,
  scale: scale
});
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: statsLoss,
  description: 'NP_forest_loss'});
  
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: statsGain,
  description: 'NP_forest_gain'});
```

Part 2: I tried to download the polygons as shapefiles but when I tried it didn't work, is there a piece of code to take the whole feature collection and then download individual shapefiles rather than just one shapefile with all locations?

Here is a link to my code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Ftravelmark85%2Fg_engine_course%3Aforest_loss_activity